# SSL inheritance on DNS CNAME

Tags: ssl, dns, cname

If I create an SSL Certificate for `secure.mydomain.com` and I create the following DNS record:

```
alias.otherdomain.com CNAME secure.mydomain.com
```

So that `alias.otherdomain.com` points to `secure.mydomain.com`, will the SSL certificate be valid if I surf to `https://alias.otherdomain.com` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it won't. The browser (or other application) will request alias.otherdomain.com and will compare this particular name to contents of presented certificate. The application knows nothing about your DNS aliases.

Update: Donal Fellows reminds me about multidomain (including wildcard) certificates. Some (but not all) CAs offer such certificates so if you buy one of those, then your scheme will work. But otherwise my answer applies.

Comment: But the SSL certificate could say that it's also for `alias.otherdomain.com` as well as `secure.mydomain.com` via a subjectAltName extension. Of course, CAs charge extra for signing such things.